# Percorrer todas strings por delimitador no campo e gerar uma coluna com o resultado

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SET @contador := 0;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX("BOX 01;BOX 02;BOX 03;BOX 04;BOX 05;BOX 06;BOX 07;BOX 08;BOX 09;BOX 10;BOX 11;BOX 12;BOX 13;BOX 14;BOX 15;BOX 16;BOX 17;BOX 18;BOX 19;BOX 20;BOX 21;BOX 22;BOX 23;BOX 24;BOX 25;BOX 26;BOX 27;BOX 28;BOX 29;BOX 30"
                         , ';', @contador := @contador + 1)
                       , ';', -1) AS box
       , @contador as contagem FROM galpao
```

com esse `select` funciona tipo como um *loop* for porem somente apresenta 13 registro sendo que existem 30. no caso na minha tabela o campo e tipo text entao independente de quantos registro existam no campo preciso que eles apareçam em todos em coluna e nao somente os 13. estive pesquisando e parece que o problema esta na funcao nativa o `SUBSTRING_INDEX` q apenas executa 13 vezes a busca.

detalhe isso tem que ser em um `select` - se for possível.

Comment: Não encontrei problema com seu select. quando você o `select * from galpao ` tem os 30 registro ?

Comment: entao, esses box estão todos em um campo da tabela galpao do tipo text e dai para separar eles estou utilizando delimitadores, no caso preciso fazer com que cada box se torne uma linha no resultado do select ex:

box 1
box 2
box 3
box 4
isso seria mostrado aqui com quantos tivesses cadastrados no campo, que nesse caso sao 30 mais poderiam ter bem mais.

Comment: CREATE TABLE  `galpao` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_galpao` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `box` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

INSERT INTO galpao (id, nome_galpao, box) VALUES('','galpao_1','BOX 01;BOX 02;BOX 03;BOX 04;BOX 05;BOX 06;BOX 07;BOX 08;BOX 09;BOX 10;BOX 11;BOX 12;BOX 13;BOX 14;BOX 15;BOX 16;BOX 17;BOX 18;BOX 19;BOX 20;BOX 21;BOX 22;BOX 23;BOX 24;BOX 25;BOX 26;BOX 27;BOX 28;BOX 29;BOX 30')

preciso do resultado em linha ex.:

box 1
box 2
box 3
box 4
isso seria mostrado aqui com quantos tivesses cadastrados no campo, nesse caso sao 30 mais poderiam ter bem mais.